# Где и как объявить strcpy

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int i, a, b, n;
unsigned char ch1, ch2;
char str_spisok[29][19], str[19];

cout << "input length of the list (29 or less): ";              //количесво 
фамилий 29 или меньше.
cin >> n;                                                                
//29 отвечает 30 фамилиям

cout << "\ninput names: \n";
for (i=0;i<=n;i++) gets(str_spisok[i]);


 for (a=1;a<n;a++)
     for (b=n;b>=a;b--){
         ch1=str_spisok[b-1][0];
         ch2=str_spisok[b][0];
         if (ch1>ch2){
                      strcpy(str,str_spisok[b-1]);
                      strcpy(str_spisok[b-1],str_spisok[b]);
                      strcpy(str_spisok[b],str);
                      }
         }

 cout << "\nsorted list: \n";
 for (i=0;i<=n;i++) cout << str_spisok[i] << "\n";

system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: ||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
G:\Путь к прораммированию флешке\Ввод фамилии\Ввод списка класса\Вводим список класса 1.cpp||In function 'int main(int, char**)':|
G:\Путь к прораммированию флешке\Ввод фамилии\Ввод списка класса\Вводим список класса 1.cpp|24|error: 'strcpy' was not declared in this scope|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Comment: Объявлять ничего не надо, надо включить заголовочный файл, объявляющий `strcpy`, который можно узнать заглянув [в справочник](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=strcpy&button=).

Comment: @igorekvp, сообщения об ошибках и другая дополнительная информация должна быть в самом вопросе, а не в комментариях.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для C++:

```
#include <cstring>
```

Для C/C++:

```
#include <string.h>
```